# How to Pause a method execution , and resume after client response?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, multithreading, modal-dialog

I have a mvc web application in where user send request to server. On execution of method DoSomething(int x)  , a validation occurs. So i need to send back a response on the user asking for confirmation. If the user click Yes i should continue the execution of DoSomething(int x). If user response No i will stop for the user to do some changes and resubmit again.
I have try to mimic my scenario in the code below: The idea is for you to understand the issue. 
Now the question: Is there a way to use thread? 
hint:If this was a windows form it is easy Showdialog will take care of it.

```
    public void DoSomething(int x)
    {
        // do other thing  here
        //...
        if (x > 0)
        {
            //Notify user for confirmation
            EventNotification.ModalBox("X is out of the Decision", "Do you want to proceed?");
            //httprequest will fire based on user response
            //###PAUSE HERE ####
            //wait for user response
        }

        //###RESUME HERE ####
        //Continu here  if confirmation  is YES
        x = x + 23;
        //save to database
        EventNotification.CloseBox("good");

    }

    public class EventNotification
    {
        public event System.EventHandler CloseEvent;
        public event System.EventHandler ModalBoxEvent;

        public void ModalBox(string text, string YesorNoConfirmation)
        {//raise event to open modal box 
            MyMsgBoxText = text;
            MyMsgBoxTitle = YesorNoConfirmation;
            if (ModalBoxEvent != null)
            {
                ModalBoxEvent(this, System.EventArgs.Empty);
            }
        }
        public void CloseBox(string text)
        {

            if (CloseEvent != null)
            {
                CloseEvent(this, System.EventArgs.Empty);
            }
        }

    }
```

Comment: Why not do the validation/confirmation in javascript before submitting to the server?

Comment: In a Very normal situation yes. But I am dealing with an exceptional application in a bad design for the web.(originally in windows).

Comment: *"Very normal case. I am dealing with an exceptional application application that was done in that"* I'm sorry, but I don't understand what you are saying here.

Comment: We converted a windows forms application to an MVC by keeping the all backend untouched

Comment: Unfortunately you are going to have to touch the back end, there simply isn't a good way to "pause" in MVC because what if the user navigates away (or closes the browser) while you are paused? If you used a thread, you'll have a resource sitting there waiting forever. It needs to be broken up into a 2-step process, first a Confirm, then an action, or do the confirmation in javascript.

Comment: If minimal code changes are what you are going for, WebForms would match the Windows Forms model more closely, and you'd have an easier time converting than using MVC, but you still would end up with issues. Unfortunately, the likelihood of successfully converting a Windows Form app to a Web app "with no changes to backend" is close to zero.

Comment: I agree to do some minor changes. For example inserting a System.Threading.AutoResetEvent or any other way to wait. I can also create a timout to remove these if the user never comes back

Comment: You still can't use a thread because when the client side posts its confirmation, it does it to an action, which starts the action over, it doesn't pick it up again where it left off, the concept of pausing for user input just doesn't carry over to web, you're going to have to drop the idea of pausing inside a method.

Comment: lol. Basicallly all winforms  still exist in the backend in Memory. Meaning that for each http call i have a form id where i can retrieve the form (in memory) with all property. This is a representation of what you have in client. The form is remove when user in the client close the form. So the state of the app in in memory like in the woindow. All form work perfectly. except the case of showing a dialog like i described

Comment: @user3581934 are you using some specific product for converting the app from WinForms to Web? You should specify it, otherwise the question is confusing.

Comment: Nope. There is no tools. We converted it by using a custom function to convert control to html control (for the form)

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: No, this is not possible in MVC.

Longer answer: you need to think a bit differently when working in MVC.

Two approaches come to mind:

1. Display the confirmation dialog on the client-side with JavaScript and go to the server only if the user confirms his/her choice.
2. Create a MVC view that displays the confirmation, and if the user confirms his/her choice, continue. This essentially breaks up your flow into two separate steps.

Comment: It will be a lot of work to change the logic back to JS only. There are tons of places where we have the same scenarios. removing this back to client is almost re starting from scratch(which management did not support 2 year ago)

Comment: This is not a simple MVC because the forms  still reside in the backend @Ronald Zarīts